# multiple Task for multiple folder's files processing

Tags: c#, .net-core, task

I have couple of issue what I did to process files from multiple folder. Let me first define the use case,

- I have bunch of folders inside a base directory `C:\Data`, Folder1, Folder2..... in future new folder also added.
- A 3rd party apps keeps pushing text file to these fixed folder 24/7, randomly. (every minute approx. 5 files)
- I need to write a C# window service where I need to process the files from each folder. Each folder files I need to process in parallel (I can't go one by one folder) and text files I need to process in sequence (base on their `lastwritetime`)
- Here I am creating C# `Task` for each folder to process each folder files processing in parallel. I defined a class `FolderTasks` like this,

**FolderTasks**

```
public class FolderTasks
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public Task FileProcess { get; set; }
}
```

- In main `program.cs`, I have a infinite `while` loop and every 2 minutes I am checking for any new folder (say Folder3) for my base folder `C:\Data\` and sending this information to `ProcessAsync` method of `FolderManager`.

**Question 1** - Can we eliminate infinite loop here and how to know for new folder presence?

**"Program.cs"**

```
private static async Task Main()
    {
        try
        {
            await using var resolver = Resolver.GetContainer();
            await using var scope = resolver.BeginLifetimeScope();
            var folderManager = scope.Resolve<FolderManager>();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Data\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                    await folderManager.ProcessAsync(folders);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }

                await Task.Delay(120000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

- In 'FolderManager', first I am preparing `List<FolderTasks>` for each available folder, then crating a `Task` for it.
- Then in `ProcessFolderTask` method, I am going to respective folder and at a time only fetching 2 files and processing it for cloud upload, then deleting the file. Again here we have infinite while loop as I need to run the task all time.

**Question2 - Again here can we remove infinite `while` loop.**
**- How to handle exception, if any of task have.**
**- how to make sure task should not stopped even error occurs.**
**- and overall, Is the approach is right? Is some other better way to do?**

**FolderManager.cs**

```
public class FolderManager
{
    private readonly List<FolderTasks> folderTasks = new List<FolderTasks>();

    public async Task ProcessAsync(string[] folders)
    {
        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            var ft = new FolderTasks
            {
                Path = folder,
            };

            folderTasks.Add(ft);
        }


        foreach (var fts in folderTasks)
        {
            if (fts.FileProcess == null)
            {
                fts.FileProcess = ProcessFolderTask(fts);
            }
            else
            {
                var processingTask = fts.FileProcess;
                if (processingTask.IsFaulted)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await processingTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        fts.FileProcess = ProcessFolderTask(fts);
                        processingTask.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                else if (processingTask.IsCanceled)
                {
                    fts.FileProcess = ProcessFolderTask(fts);
                    processingTask.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessFolderTask(FolderTasks fts)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var files = new DirectoryInfo(fts.Path).GetFiles()
                    .OrderBy(p => p.LastWriteTimeUtc).Take(2).ToList();

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    //some business logic to upload data to azure cloud
                    Console.WriteLine($"{file} - from {fts.Path}");

                    file.Delete();
                }

                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                await Task.Delay(120000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: _"Each folder files I need to process in parallel"_ - I doubt, this is the actual requirement. Are you _sure_ it wouldn't be enough to decouple detection from processing?

Comment: @Fildor, let us at time if I have 100 files in each folder, then I don't want to process one folder at a time and move to other folder. I need to process 2 files from each folder simultaneously.

Comment: @Sandhagen, with file watcher how to watch new folder which will create after my service host, also I need to watch all folder and process 2 files from each folder simultaneously. Can I do this?

Comment: Right. But what if you have 100 Folders with 1 File? Do you think 100 parallel Disk I/O will be a good idea? So you may consider boundaries here, too.

Comment: Take a look at [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: _"how to watch new folder"_ = [FileSystemWatcher.Created Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created?view=netcore-3.1): _"Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is created."_

Comment: Also have a look and consider using [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). So you can throw new files into a pipeline. DataFlow blocks also allow for parallel execution, just dig into it a bit.

Comment: Also the task created in line `fts.FileProcess = ProcessFolderTask(fts);` gets never awaited